# No jniopencv_core in java.library.path on Odroid X2 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, javacv, odroid

I am trying to get JavaCV running on my Odroid X2 ARM based board with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have got a simple demo program, where I want to connect to a camera attached an output the video stream. On my windows PC it works perfectly, but running the jar on the Odroid causes the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:410)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:10)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:13)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:174)
    at CameraTest.main(CameraTest.java:11)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tbb in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:401)
    ... 14 more
```

I have got the same issues on my MacBook Pro. I already read a lot in the internet, but nothing helped me to solve the problems. I compiled OpenCV 2.4.9 on the Odroid. Is this necessary or does JavaCV also work standalone?

Could you please help me to solve those errors, so that I can run my applications?

Thank you!

Comment: For MacOSX replacing the opencv.jar with https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/opencv/2.4.10-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/opencv-2.4.10-0.9.1-20141109.113201-4-macosx-x86_64.jar solved the problem for me.